# Painting TPaintBox during Drag&Drop with DragImage

Tags: delphi, drag-and-drop, delphi-2007, paintbox

In my application (Delphi 2007) I want to drag items from a ListView to a PaintBox and highlight corresponding areas in the PaintBox's OnPaint handler. However I always get ugly artefacts. Do you have any advice how I can get rid of them?

**Test project:** Just create a new VCL application and replace the code in Unit1.pas with the following. Then start the app and drag list items over the rectangle in the PaintBox.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows,
  Messages,
  SysUtils,
  Variants,
  Classes,
  Graphics,
  Controls,
  Forms,
  Dialogs,
  ExtCtrls,
  ComCtrls,
  ImgList;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  private
    PaintBox1: TPaintBox;
    ListView1: TListView;
    ImageList1: TImageList;
    FRectIsHot: Boolean;
    function GetSensitiveRect: TRect;
    procedure PaintBox1DragOver(Sender, Source: TObject; X, Y: Integer;
      State: TDragState; var Accept: Boolean);
    procedure PaintBox1Paint(Sender: TObject);
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

uses
  TypInfo;

const
  IconIDs: array[TMsgDlgType] of PChar = (IDI_EXCLAMATION, IDI_HAND,
    IDI_ASTERISK, IDI_QUESTION, nil);

{ TForm1 }

constructor TForm1.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
var
  Panel1: TPanel;
  mt: TMsgDlgType;
  Icon: TIcon;
  li: TListItem;
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  Width := 600;
  Height := 400;

  ImageList1 := TImageList.Create(Self);
  ImageList1.Name := 'ImageList1';
  ImageList1.Height := 32;
  ImageList1.Width := 32;

  ListView1 := TListView.Create(Self);
  ListView1.Name := 'ListView1';
  ListView1.Align := alLeft;
  ListView1.DragMode := dmAutomatic;
  ListView1.LargeImages := ImageList1;

  Panel1 := TPanel.Create(Self);
  Panel1.Name := 'Panel1';
  Panel1.Caption := 'Drag list items here';
  Panel1.Align := alClient;

  PaintBox1 := TPaintBox.Create(Self);
  PaintBox1.Name := 'PaintBox1';
  PaintBox1.Align := alClient;
  PaintBox1.ControlStyle := PaintBox1.ControlStyle + [csDisplayDragImage];
  PaintBox1.OnDragOver := PaintBox1DragOver;
  PaintBox1.OnPaint := PaintBox1Paint;
  PaintBox1.Parent := Panel1;

  ListView1.Parent := Self;
  Panel1.Parent := Self;

  Icon := TIcon.Create;
  try
    for mt := Low(TMsgDlgType) to High(TMsgDlgType) do
      if Assigned(IconIDs[mt]) then
      begin
        li := ListView1.Items.Add;
        li.Caption := GetEnumName(TypeInfo(TMsgDlgType), Ord(mt));
        Icon.Handle := LoadIcon(0, IconIDs[mt]);
        li.ImageIndex := ImageList1.AddIcon(Icon);
      end;
  finally
    Icon.Free;
  end;
end;

function TForm1.GetSensitiveRect: TRect;
begin
  Result := PaintBox1.ClientRect;
  InflateRect(Result, -PaintBox1.Width div 4, -PaintBox1.Height div 4);
end;

procedure TForm1.PaintBox1Paint(Sender: TObject);
var
  r: TRect;
begin
  r := GetSensitiveRect;
  if FRectIsHot then
  begin
    PaintBox1.Canvas.Pen.Width := 5;
    PaintBox1.Canvas.Brush.Style := bsSolid;
    PaintBox1.Canvas.Brush.Color := clAqua;
  end
  else
  begin
    PaintBox1.Canvas.Pen.Width := 1;
    PaintBox1.Canvas.Brush.Style := bsClear;
  end;
  PaintBox1.Canvas.Rectangle(r.Left, r.Top, r.Right, r.Bottom);
end;

procedure TForm1.PaintBox1DragOver(Sender, Source: TObject; X,
  Y: Integer; State: TDragState; var Accept: Boolean);
var
  r: TRect;
  MustRepaint: Boolean;
begin
  MustRepaint := False;

  if State = dsDragEnter then
  begin
    FRectIsHot := False;
    MustRepaint := True;
  end
  else
  begin
    r := GetSensitiveRect;
    Accept := PtInRect(r, Point(X, Y));

    if Accept <> FRectIsHot then
    begin
      FRectIsHot := Accept;
      MustRepaint := True;
    end;
  end;

  if MustRepaint then
    PaintBox1.Invalidate;
end;

end.
```

**Edit:** Here is a picture of the glitch:[DragImage artefact http://img269.imageshack.us/img269/6535/15778780.png](http://img269.imageshack.us/img269/6535/15778780.png)

I expect to see the complete blue rectangle with thick border. However beneath the drag image one can see the un-highlighted rectangle.

**Edit 2:** [This site](http://www.vbaccelerator.com/home/net/code/Controls/ImageList/Sophisticated_Drag_Drop_Images/article.asp) talks about "Painting Issues":

> The ImageList SDK notes that when
>   drawing the drag image you can get
>   issues with updates or screen painting
>   unless you use the ImageList_DragLeave
>   API function to hide the drag image
>   whilst the painting occurs (which is
>   what the HideDragImage method in the
>   class does). Unfortunately, if you
>   don't own the control that's being
>   painted doing this isn't really an
>   option.

I don't have the problem mentioned in the last sentence. Nevertheless I wasn't able to find the right place and the right imagelist (it's **not** ImageList1 in my test project - probably ListView1.GetDragImages) to call ImageList_DragLeave.

Comment: I have copied the source code into D2009 and ran it. There were no glitches no matter which object was dragged. Running Vista btw.

Comment: OK, that is a hint that D2007, XP or my graphics card might be the culprit. Thanks for testing!

Comment: I just tested it on my home PC (XP, Turbo Delphi) and it looks exactly like the above picture.

Comment: I believe this could be the XP problem. I have XP installed in virtual machine and have D7 and D2007, both were glitching.

Comment: I'd guess it works on Vista only if desktop composition is enabled (Aero)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is to hide the drag image before the paint box is redrawn, and to show it again after that. If you replace this code in your question:

```
procedure TForm1.PaintBox1DragOver(Sender, Source: TObject; X,
  Y: Integer; State: TDragState; var Accept: Boolean);
var
  r: TRect;
  MustRepaint: Boolean;
begin
  MustRepaint := False;

  if State = dsDragEnter then
  begin
    FRectIsHot := False;
    MustRepaint := True;
  end
  else
  begin
    r := GetSensitiveRect;
    Accept := PtInRect(r, Point(X, Y));

    if Accept <> FRectIsHot then
    begin
      FRectIsHot := Accept;
      MustRepaint := True;
    end;
  end;

  if MustRepaint then
    PaintBox1.Invalidate;
end;
```

with this

```
procedure TForm1.PaintBox1DragOver(Sender, Source: TObject; X,
  Y: Integer; State: TDragState; var Accept: Boolean);
var
  r: TRect;
begin
  if State = dsDragEnter then
  begin
    FRectIsHot := False;
    PaintBox1.Invalidate;
  end
  else
  begin
    r := GetSensitiveRect;
    Accept := PtInRect(r, Point(X, Y));

    if Accept <> FRectIsHot then
    begin
      FRectIsHot := Accept;
      ImageList_DragShowNolock(False);
      try
        PaintBox1.Refresh;
      finally
        ImageList_DragShowNolock(True);
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

it should work. Well, it does for me with Delphi 2007 on Windows XP 64 bit.

And kudos for the demonstration code in your question, excellent way to let us see the problem.

Comment: Works for me under XP 32bit/Turbo Delphi. I still discovered a (veeeery) minor glitch: Alt-Tab while dragging leaves traces on the **other** application. But who does something like that deserves nothing better. :-)

Comment: @Ulrich: I don't think all such glitches can be fixed in the application. Drag and drop is a difficult process with a lot of special handling on the system level. Raymond Chen has quite some articles on the topic of dragging and `LockWindowUpdate()` in particular. There's much interesting information in these.

Comment: I figured that much. Therefore I'm happy with your solution. And yes, Raymond's stuff is very interesting. I read OldNewThing regularly.

Comment: I implemented your solution to our *real* app and it works fine. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Tested on XP, Delphi 2010 - I get the artifacts, so it's XP related and not fixed in D2010

Edit:

Upon further investigation - if you drag an icon so that the mouse only just enters the box (but the icon doesn't) then the box is drawn correctly, it's only when the icon enters the paintbox that the artifacts occur.

I added code so that if state was dsDragMove then it would force a repaint and this worked, but suffered from flicker

Comment: I tried that too, and as you said, it flickered badly. Also IIRC the artefacts weren't gone - they were just smaller.